# Please assist me in building this query

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, join, greatest-n-per-group

I want to extract rows of group by `rls_id` but with latest/recent `date`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_revisions` 
WHERE `date` IN (SELECT MAX(`date`) 
                 FROM `tbl_revisions` 
                 GROUP BY `rls_id`) 
GROUP BY `rls_id`
```

The above query works well but I don't want to use subqueries. I need some other way around.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_revisions` 
(
  `id` int(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rls_id` int(21) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user` int(21) NOT NULL,
  `data` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=66 ;
```

Edit:  Needs a faster way

Okay. i got 2 working queries thanks to both @Bill Karwin and @OMG Ponies .

I am pasting Explain for both queries here so other will learn better

```
Bill Karwin :

SELECT r1.*
FROM `tbl_revisions` r1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_revisions` r2
  ON (r1.`rls_id` = r2.`rls_id` AND r1.`date` < r2.`date`)
WHERE r2.`rls_id` IS NULL;
```

[image]

---

```
OMG Ponies:

SELECT t.* 
  FROM TBL_REVISIONS t
  JOIN (SELECT rls_id,
               MAX(date) AS max_date
          FROM TBL_REVISIONS
      GROUP BY rls_id) x ON x.rls_id = t.rls_id
                        AND x.max_date = t.date
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any other keys on the table? You might benefit from adding a multi column index over (rls_id,date).

Comment: BTW, this query is ambiguous, because you're getting non-aggregated columns (`*`) from aggregated data (`group by rls_id`). This may fly in MYSQL, but in other SQL databases, such as postgresql, will call you out on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM `tbl_revisions` r1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_revisions` r2
  ON (r1.`rls_id` = r2.`rls_id` AND r1.`date` < r2.`date`)
WHERE r2.`rls_id` IS NULL;
```

Comment: it is not working , returned wrong results. (when i ran mine it returns 2 but this query is just empty)

Comment: I can't see this being faster than a query w/ subquery.

Comment: @Arsheep: Apologies, I made a mistake in the WHERE clause.  It should be where r2.rls_id is null, not r1.  Try it with my edit.

Comment: @Kendall: This is plenty fast if one defines a compound index on (rls_id, date) as you suggested in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Without using subqueries? OK:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM TBL_REVISIONS t
  JOIN (SELECT rls_id,
               MAX(date) AS max_date
          FROM TBL_REVISIONS
      GROUP BY rls_id) x ON x.rls_id = t.rls_id
                        AND x.max_date = t.date
```

Some might call it a subselect, but `x` is more accurately referred to as a derived table or inline view.  Subselects are typically SELECT statements within the SELECT clause itself, like:

```
SELECT ...,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)...)
```

Anyways, check the tag "greatest-n-per-group" for other various examples.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is represented on the MySQL site as a 'groupwise max' problem. Looks like OMG Ponies got it right on -- you can't quite get away without any subqueries but OMG Ponies' JOIN-ed version uses an "uncorrelated" subquery, which is more efficient:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_revisions WHERE date = MAX(date) FROM tbl_revisions GROUP BY rls_id;
```

I honestly haven't tried this, but give it a shot.

Comment: i tried already , cant use MAX function in comparison so didnt worked